# Setting width (automatically) of a div when two divs are floated

Tags: html, css

I have the following  **HTML**:

```
<div style="width:300px;background:yellow;">
    <div style="float:left;border:solid 2px red;"><!--Img Div-->
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/despicable-me-2-minions/128/Dancing-minion-icon.png">
    </div>
    <div style="border:solid 2px lime;float:left;"><!--Text Div-->
      Banana!
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I need to set the width of the *Text Div* such that it *occupies the remaining width*. I know this can be done by using ***width*** style attribute as `width:164px;`. What I needed to know is: Can this be done ***without setting the width manually using other css properties***?

Comment: setting width to 100% pushes it down, if that's what you meant..doesn't help

Comment: I don't want to do any calculations.. that's what I meant.. :)

Comment: You want a CSS property that will determine the remaining width of the parent element? Instead of you giving it a width of 164px, that the browser will do it for you? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: Reason for downvote? I thought it was a valid question!

Comment: @JosanIracheta You don't get the point here. The parent div already has a specified width of 300px. Check the accepted answer. Now you've heard of "such a thing". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove `float:left` from the text div

2) Set `overflow:hidden` (or auto) on the text div

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zxnn6jxn/1/)**

This creates a new block formatting context which causes the text div to fill the remaining width

Comment: Look at the fiddle again - see how the border only wraps around the text and not the image. This is exactly what the OP wants: "I need to set the width of the Text Div such that it occupies the remaining width"

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - NB: If you **just** remove the float - then the text doesn't take the *remaining* width - it takes up 100% width (including the image). That's why you need overflow

Comment: It isn't exactly what OP wants. The title itself says **"_Setting width of a div when two divs are floated_"**.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py - but in the content of the question he clarifies that he actually wants the div to take up the **remaining width**

Comment: If I understood the question correctly the OP wants - To set the remaining width without removing the floats.

Comment: My understanding (reading between the lines) is that he doesn't actually need both floats - he's just describing the current state of the code and the basic layout of how he wants the elements to sit

Comment: @Danield Thanks. Solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="width:300px;background:yellow;">
        <div style="float:left;border:solid 2px red;"><!--Img Div-->
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/despicable-me-2-minions/128/Dancing-minion-icon.png">
        </div>
        <div style="border:solid 2px lime;display:block; text-align: center; overflow: hidden;"><!--Text Div-->
          Banana!
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

I added `display:block; text-align: center; overflow: hidden;` and removed the `float: left` from the text div

Answer (score 0):

use `display:table` for parent and `display:table-cell` for the one which you want the `width` to fill

Note : moved your styles outside

```css
.top {
  width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
}
.inside {
  float: left;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
.txt {
  border: solid 2px lime;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="inside">
    <!--Img Div-->
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/despicable-me-2-minions/128/Dancing-minion-icon.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    <!--Text Div-->Banana!</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```